# How to set default configuration values for each store view

Tags: magento2, email-templates

I have a configuration field which I am using to store email template value. I am assigning default email template id using `config.xml` file. This works perfectly fine for defaut store view.

Now, I have an arabic store view which has **rtl** email templates. I have created separate email template for rtl layout with specific id. I want to assign **rtl** email template to my rtl store view using `config.xml` file. Is there any way to achieve it? How can I set default email template for a specific store view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually add store and website nodes to the config.xml.

```
<stores>
    <store_code>
```

```
<websites>
 <website_code>
```

Pseudo example:

```
<stores>
 <default>
  <design>
   <head>
    <includes>
```